# Swift - custom UITableViewCell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having troubles customizing my `cells` inside my `UITableView`. I would like to have a `UIButton` on the left but somehow the `UIButton` only appears inside the first `cell`:

[image]

This is how I create the `UIButton` inside my `UITableViewCell`:

```
class WhishCell: UITableViewCell {

let checkButton: UIButton =  {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.backgroundColor = .red
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()



public static let reuseID = "WhishCell"

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.addSubview(checkButton)
    self.backgroundColor = .clear

}
}
```

**My `TableView`:**

```
class WhishlistTableViewController: UITableViewController {

public var wishList = [Wish]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
    self.tableView.register(WhishCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID)
    self.wishList.append(Wish(withWishName: "Test"))

}

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return wishList.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID, for: indexPath)
    let currentWish = self.wishList[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentWish.wishName
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear

    return cell
}
```

Does anyone know why it only appears only on the first `cell`?? Kind of new to `TableViews` so I'm happy with every help :)

Comment: The issue is not with how you create the button, but rather how you use the table cell. Can you add your code inside of the table view?

Comment: Try applying constraints to button.

Comment: @Jacob sure, just updated my code :) The data array get's appended from another `ViewController` where I basically just call `whishlist.append`

Comment: @GauravParvadiya why would that make any difference ? I will try it :)

Comment: Try adding your subviews in the table views layoutSubviews method. So instead of adding the button in init add it in layoutSubviews

Comment: @GauravParvadiya that was actually it ??! Do you know why that happens?

Comment: @Chris Reason is button needs frame or constraints.You were adding button as a subview but never specified position of it. So button was actually added but wasn't visible because of constraints.

Comment: @Chris:
1) try to add this button like this: self.contentView.addSubview(checkButton)
2) Don't forget about setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
3) add constraints to your button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIButton is subclass of UIView so initialization of UIbutton requires frame or constraints to specify it's position. Try applying constraints to `checkButton` will solve your issue.

Comment: Also, if you aren't using constraints remove the     `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` line from your code.

Answer (score 1):

As others are suggesting the reason for this is that you are never defining layout constraints for your button.  Here is a sample update to your `init` to include the layout, though there are many ways you could do this.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
  super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
  self.addSubview(checkButton)
  self.checkButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
  self.checkButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
  self.checkButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
  self.checkButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
  self.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

Of course I'm just making up constraints here, but this would achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should add constrains to the UIButton because the parent view needs to know where the button must be. Also if the view has other components inside, you have to declare that instead.

In conclusion, you have to tell to the component that you want to add witch components have around.

Try with this

```
self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: checkButton, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: checkButton, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textLabel, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: checkButton, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: checkButton, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
```